# React - handle Redirect URI to Spotify in Docker with Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, spotify

I have this folder structure in my docker app:

```
nginx/
     dev.conf
client/
      src/
         Spotify.js
```

this is how I call `redirect uri` from `client`:

> Spotify.js

```
  class SpotifyAuth extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super()

  this.handleRedirect = this.handleRedirect.bind(this)
  }

  getHashParams() {
    var hashParams = {};
    var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
        q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    e = r.exec(q)
    while (e) {
       hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
       e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }

  handleRedirect = (e) => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8888" )
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
    //e.preventDefault();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='button__container'>
        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleRedirect}
        ><strong>CONNECT YOUR SPOTIFY ACCOUNT</strong>
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default SpotifyAuth;
```

> docker-compose-dev.yml

```
 nginx:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8888:8888

    depends_on:
      - web
      - client

  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3007:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

> nginx/dev.conf

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

How do authorize this properly and handle token from `Spotify.js`?

EDIT:

I have tried the solution proposed by answer below, first with localhost:8888 and then with localhost:3000 (both valid as redirect urls at Spotify dev.)

It only works with 8888, and even so:

App dumps `token` at `localStorage`, but **hangs** there with the following alert on the browser:

[image]

then, if I click on the OK, and only IF, it redirects.

what is wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing from `localhost` to `localhost:8888` so the user can be further redirected to spotify?

Comment: for `localhost` I have nginx listening at location `client:3000`, which I user for another register and login flow (for the app REST API itself, with its own token). I don't know if this is best practice, however.

Comment: Are you able to change the `redirect_uri` for the oauth client registered with Spotify?

Comment: sure. if your solution requires this, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should redirect from `localhost` directly to `spotify.com`, missing out `localhost:8888`.

I have moved the code on `localhost:8888` in to the React component to handle the redirection and saving of access token when you are redirected back.

```
const stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';
const client_id = 'myid'; // Your client id
const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000'; // Your redirect uri
const scope =
  'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private';

function generateRandomString(length) {
  let text = '';
  const possible =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  return text;
}

class SpotifyAuth extends React.Component {
  getHashParams() {
    const hashParams = {};
    const r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g;
    const q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    let e = r.exec(q);
    while (e) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
      e = r.exec(q);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const params = this.getHashParams();

    const access_token = params.access_token;
    const state = params.state;
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem(stateKey);
    localStorage.setItem('spotify_access_token', access_token);
    localStorage.getItem('spotify_access_token');

    if (access_token && (state == null || state !== storedState)) {
      alert('There was an error during the authentication');
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(stateKey);
    }

    // DO STUFF WITH ACCESS TOKEN HERE
  }

  handleRedirect() {
    const state = generateRandomString(16);
    localStorage.setItem(stateKey, state);

    let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    url += '?response_type=token';
    url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(client_id);
    url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scope);
    url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri);
    url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);

    window.location = url;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="button__container">
        <button className="button" onClick={this.handleRedirect}>
          <strong>CONNECT YOUR SPOTIFY ACCOUNT</strong>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `componentDidMount` function will run when the component is loaded: [see more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

You can also read more on [OAuth2 here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2), you are using the Implict flow.

Comment: simply `http://localhost/`as URI, with no port whatsoever, throws the error 'that was an error with authentication'. I get the token at console, though, so we're half way there...

Comment: app is not redirected back to localhost, also.

Comment: Forgot to say you need to update the `redirect_uri` on the Spotify OAuth client to `http://localhost/`. I'm not able to replicate the alert.

Comment: you mean update with spotify api? done that. added `http://localhost/`, saved it, and this URI throws an error: INVALID_CLIENT, invalid URI, and if I change redirect back to `http://localhost:8888`, it gets token, but alerts me an undefined error at authorization

Comment: aren't we maybe missing the `ajax` call, with `fecth()` or `axios.get()`? call to uri in `handleDirect`? because auth-server listens to port 8888, but we're passing no port to the service listen to. remember we're in a docker container.

Comment: Invalid client suggests the `clientId` could be incorrect, can you confirm you've replaced it with the correct one? We also shouldn't make any direct HTTP request until we get the access token and shouldn't make any difference if it's in a Docker container if it's being accessed through the browser.

Comment: `clientID`is correct, I've confirmed. I asked you because each service in docker needs a container listening at a port, right? my working example had `auth-server` listening on `8888:8888`

Comment: and my client service listens to ports:
      `- 3007:3000`

Comment: That's my mistake then, it should be `http://localhost:3000`. Will update answer as well.